# I want to make a powershell script that call another powershell script

Tags: powershell

So i have lets say a powershell script called `CallMePlease.ps1`

This script will take parameters / arguments and then does some a process. How do I append the arguments to the call when I call this script from `MAIN.ps1`? Code I have so far:

```
$ScriptPath = C:\Tmp\PAL\PAL\PAL\PAL.ps1
$Log 'C:\Users\k0530196\Documents\log.csv'
$ThresholdFile 'C:\Program Files\PAL\PAL\template.xml'
$Interval 'AUTO'
$IsOutputHtml $True
$HtmlOutputFileName '[LogFileName]_PAL_ANALYSIS_[DateTimeStamp].htm'
$IsOutputXml $True
$XmlOutputFileName '[LogFileName]_PAL_ANALYSIS_[DateTimeStamp].xml'
$AllCounterStats $False
$NumberOfThreads 1
$IsLowPriority $False

$cmd = "$ScriptPath\.\PAL.ps1"

Invoke-Expression "$cmd $Log $ThresholdFile $Interval $IsOutputHtml $HtmlOutputFileName $IsOutputXml $XmlOutputFileName $AllCounterStats $NumberOfThreads"
```

Comment: I think you are missing some `=`s in there as well

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed those were typos. :)

Comment: Sorry Matt , i didnt pick up where i missed the = ... 

also i'm think of adding this as the first line : 

$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName

Good Idea ?

Comment: Guys i tried running my script i got the following error : 

Unexpected token 'C:\Shawn\pc\log.csv' in expression or statement.
At C:\Shaan\PAL\PAL\Pal\ScriptReport_Create.ps1:2 char:70
+ $Log 'C:\Shawn\pc\log.csv' <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (C:\Shawn\pc\log.csv:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: That would be the missing = I think. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you posted you are missing several =s in your assignment statements. For instance this line:

$Log 'C:\Users\k0530196\Documents\log.csv'

Should be this:

$Log ***=*** 'C:\Users\k0530196\Documents\log.csv'

You will need to do that in all the instances where you are trying to assign a value to a variable.

I would do it like this:

```
. $cmd $Log $ThresholdFile $Interval $IsOutputHtml $HtmlOutputFileName $IsOutputXml $XmlOutputFileName $AllCounterStats $NumberOfThreads
```

Comment: hmmmm interesting but here you dont specify the powershell script im calling .. ? from my understanding that just stores the arguments that are suppose to be passed on to ps1 in Env var $cmd

Comment: $cmd is the script that you are calling right? It is in there.

Comment: yup true it is, i noticed after however now that i try the script i get the parse error regarding log ... it's weird i though it would have worked.. .

Comment: oops now i feel kinda dumb :( , let me try this out thank you EBGreen